# Thymeleaf: Add to existing values instead of replacing them

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is there a way to tell `Thymeleaf` to add parameters to a tag instead of overriding them?

Example:

```
 <div class="a" th:class=${x ? 'b' : 'c'}>
```

Should result in either

```
<div class="a b">
```

or

```
<div class="a c">
```

Regards

Comment: `th:classappend` solves the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to do this would be

```
th:attr="class=|a ${x ? 'b' : 'c'}|"
```