# Thymeleaf conditional classappend not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133807/thymeleaf-how-to-use-conditionals-to-dynamically-add-remove-a-css-class).

I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="arrow-steps clearfix">
<div th:each="caseStep : ${getAppCaseStepList}"
                                        th:class="arbitrary"
                                        th:classappend="${caseStep.casestepname == '${appCaseCurrentStep}'} ? 'step current' : 'step'"
                                        th:text="${caseStep.casestepname}">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

where `${appCaseCurrentStep}` is a model attribute (a String)  which I am sending through GET in my controller method.

But somehow I am not able to set "step current" class to the element for this condition:

```
${caseStep.casestepname == '${appCaseCurrentStep}'
```

I am trying to set/append "step current" where my condition is true (String comparison) . What am I missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: `'${appCaseCurrentStep}'` means the literal string `${appCaseCurrentStep}`.

Comment: when I use `${appCaseCurrentStep}`  it throws exception: `there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'`

Comment: And if you try just `== appCaseCurrentStep`?

Comment: Lol.. I was typing the answer myself while you commented this. Yeah you are right.. that fixed it. ! Thanks Chrylis.

Comment: The `${}` identifies _an entire expression_, so inside it you don't need to restart a "new" expression.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I read that now Chrylis. Thanks so much for your unparalleled effort and info on this. You are awesome. I learned something new today.!

Answer (score 0):

Found it [here](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-if-comparing-objects-td4026839.html). !

**The cause:** There should NOT be an additional { inside the expression ${...}.

**Solution:** The following expression did the trick for me:

```
<div th:each="caseStep : ${getAppCaseStepList}"
                                        th:class="asdfstep"
                                        th:classappend="${caseStep.casestepname == appCaseCurrentStep} ? 'step current' : 'step'"
                                        th:text="${caseStep.casestepname}"></div>
```