# Implement field validation via Thymeleaf (migrate from Freemarker to Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring, frontend, thymeleaf

I'm developing one little Spring Boot App with user login and registration. I want to implement my own registration system with field validation. For validation I use my own implementation of `org.springframework.validation.Validator` in controller. Vaidator catches all errors from `bindingResult` in controller and send it to frontend in `model` field:

```
@PostMapping("/registration")
    public String signUpUser(User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult,
                             Model model) {
        validator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            Map<String, String> errors = ControllerUtils.getFieldErrors(bindingResult);
            model.mergeAttributes(errors);
            return "registration";
        }
        return "registration";
```

If there will be any validation errors, `Map<String, String> errors` will hold all that erorrs. For example, if user while registration won't fill field `firstName` map will hold object like: `"firstNameError" -> "Please, fill the field"`, and so on.

In my previous project I've used Freemarker as template engine and on frontend side code of some element were looking like that:

```
 <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="inputFirstName"
           class="form-control ${(firstNameError??)?string('is-invalid','')}"
           placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
    <div class="text-left invalid-feedback m-1 ml-1">
        <#if (firstNameError)??>
            ${firstNameError}
        </#if>
    </div>
```

So when I had an error with user's first name - my input changed class to `class="form control  is-invalid"` and it highlight field with errors, after that it displays an error message in div

Now I use Thymeleaf as a template engine. To display text of error I use

```
<div th:if="${firstNameError}" class="invalid-feedback">
        <a th:text="${firstNameError}"></a>
    </div>
```

But how can I change dynamicaly `class` of `<input...` to highlight fiend with errors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thymeleaf classappend `th:classappend` like this:

`<input type="text" name="firstName" id="inputFirstName" th:classappend="${condition} ? conditionTrueClass : conditionFalseClass "/>`

please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133807/thymeleaf-how-to-use-conditionals-to-dynamically-add-remove-a-css-class).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a conditional statement in your class to evaluate whether it should use an "error class"

Example:

```
<p  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}? error">Invalid Age</p>

<style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

> Another Thymeleaf attribute th:errors gives us the ability to display
> all errors on the specified selector, say email:

```
<div>
    <label for="email">Email</label> <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" />
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errorclass="error" th:errors="*{email}" />
</div>
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-error-messages